# What does {handleButton}: {handleButton:()=>void} mean in the example

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am wondering what the part {handleButton}: {handleButton:()=>void} means inside the parameter of the function. Is it a typescript syntax, a es6 syntax or something else?

```
const button = ({ handleButton }: { handleButton: () => void }) => (
    <button onClick={handleButton}>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is typescript.

The syntax in the left part of the colon is object destructuring to access the `handleButton` property of the argument passed in.
So the button function must be called with an object having containing this property. For example:

```
button({ a: 'hello', handleButton: () => console.log('hey') });
```

The right part of the colon is the type of what is on left side. Here the `handleButton` property is declared to be a function that takes nothing and returns nothing.

Comment: "is declared to be an arrow function" --- any function, not necessary arrow. `() => void` is a typescript function declaration "from nothing to void", not JS arrow function syntax.

Comment: What about the following
```export function getValues({ currentValue = 0, program }: Params): ReturnValue { ... }```
I get the first part where the object passed in should have the properties currentValue and program which are of type `Params`, but what about the `: ReturnValue` notation? which part of the function declaration is it referring to?